# Failed to fetch using a form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the [AniList API](https://github.com/AniList/ApiV2-GraphQL-Docs) to make some requests and load the data.
The first request I'm doing it works well (note that the page loads with some covers), but when I'm using the search button I get `failed to fetch`. Because the first time worked, but not when modifying the query, I thought that might be wrong in the way I was modifying it, but after a double check, I only modify `variables.search` and then I proceed to do the same as the first time I'm loading the page, so I don't really know why it's failing. I also tried to modify the first query, when the page is loading, and it works, so I don't think it has anything to do with the API.

Here's the code

```js
const resultsEl = document.getElementById("container-results");
const submitBtnEl = document.getElementById("submit-button");
const inputTxtEl = document.getElementById("input-txt")

var query = `
query ($id: Int, $page: Int, $perPage: Int, $search: String) {
  Page (page: $page, perPage: $perPage) {
    pageInfo {
      total
      currentPage
      lastPage
      hasNextPage
      perPage
    }
    media (id: $id, search: $search) {
      id
      title {
        romaji,
        english,
      }
      type
      coverImage {
          large
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

var variables = {
    search: "Pokemon",
    page: 1,
    perPage: 5000
};

var url = 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: query,
            variables: variables
        })
    };



fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse)
                   .then(handleData)
                   .catch(handleError);

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.json().then(function (json) {
        return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
    });
}

function handleData(data) {
    processData(data);
}

function handleError(error) {
    console.error(error);
    alert('Error, check console');
}

function processData(data) {
    let processedData = [];
    queryResults = data.data.Page.media;
    for (let i = 0; i < queryResults.length; i++) {
        let obj = {}
        obj.title = queryResults[i].title.romaji;
        obj.image = queryResults[i].coverImage.large;
        processedData.push(obj);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < processedData.length; i++) {
        let img_div = document.createElement("div");
        img_div.className = "cover-Image"
        img_div.innerHTML += processedData[i].title;
        img_div.innerHTML += "<img width=250 height=400 src=" + processedData[i].image + ">";
        resultsEl.appendChild(img_div);
    }    

}

submitBtnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const userQuery = inputTxtEl.value;
    if (userQuery !== "") {
        variables.search = userQuery;
        options.body = JSON.stringify({
            query: query,
            variables: variables
        })
        fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse)
                   .then(handleData)
                   .catch(handleError);
    }
    else {
        resultsEl.innerHTML = "";
    }
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}


.container-results {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cover-Image{
    padding: .3em;
    margin: .1em;
    width:300px;
    color:white;
}

img{
    margin: 0.5em;
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
    #nani{
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Working with api's example</title>
    <!--Bootstrap related things-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Manga search</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 mx-auto">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="input-txt" type="search" placeholder="Place title" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="submit-button" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>    


<!--RESULTS-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-results" id="container-results"> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing submit button to type-button or use event.preventDefault() while submitting the form i.e. submitBtnEl.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {ev.preventDefault() ... this way you can see updated data in the Network tab without whole page refresh, after that you need to update the data on the page with new result set.

Comment: @Vishal I can't spot the error neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vishal is correct. This is throwing an error because you are navigating away from the page when they submit.

Change your event listener to start like this and the problem goes away:

```
submitBtnEl.addEventListener("click", e => { 
   e.preventDefault();
```

When the user navigates away, the request is aborted, thus the error handler fires.

You can see this in action (before you fix it as above) by looking at the network tab. The request shows "cancelled", i.e. the browser cancelled the request.

It's a little confusing here, because the order of events is:

1. User clicks the submit button
2. The event listener you created runs
3. Inside of it, your `fetch` fires, including the establishment of its error handler
4. When your event listener finishes, the **default** event handler runs. Since this is a form, and the button was a 'submit' type, the default event handler is to submit the form. When no action URL is given, it presumes the handler is the same page.
5. The browser begins the process of navigating (i.e. submitting) to the same page.
6. The browser cancels the `fetch` request, since the user is navigating "away" from the current page.
7. The `fetch` request, having been cancelled, has now errored, and thus the error handler fires
8. Your `alert` runs inside the error handler, pausing the execution of the page, including the navigation

So at that point it seems like they haven't navigated yet, but the process has already started enough to have cancelled the request.